# Top bar corruption/rendering issue

Tags: gnome, display

Installed Focal last week. For the most part things are working okay (still miss Unity) except that half the time when I come back from the lockscreen, the top bar turns transparent with oversized icons. The tropdowns are also transparent, and the Windows key search simply clears the screen, with nothing visible of what I type.

on login:
[image: screen on login]

corrupted

[image: transparent and oversized]

Using a GeForce1050 card with the Nvidia drivers, but I really don't think it's a driver issue, also I had the same issue with the Nouveau drivers. It's not a consistent problem, either; occasionally

I keep root on a separate partition from /home, but for reasons not worth going into, instead of installing 20.04 over 16.04, I reformatted and repartitioned and copied a /home backup -- only reason I bring it up is because I wonder if something left there is messing with my configuration?

As you can see, I've put in a fair number of Gnome extensions (and learned the quality is kind of inconsistent) so maybe the culprit's in there?

Comment: Another symptom: though the screen lock timeout is set for 15 minutes (not full lock, I don't pw protect it at home) sometimes the screen blanks only seconds or minutes after I stop typing, though when I return, most often there won't be any corruption.

Comment: More info: updating some of the extensions for the moment seems to have solved the corruption problems. The screen timeout situation however has gotten worse -- syslog shows countless instances on the order of every 3-4 seconds of "ep 22 08:05:14 Swann gnome-shell[14113]: Object .Gjs_ui_pointerA11yTimeout_PieTimer (0x5566dc58fc20), has been already dealloc
ated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as de
stroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs."

Answer (score 0):

I'd hoped to find another way out but the solution was just to reset the desktop using

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```